# Edit several hundred Protocol Buffer serialized messages read from database

Tags: java, database, performance, protocol-buffers

For an operation on my application, I need to read from database & then **edit several hundred Protocol Buffer serialized messages**. In each PB message, there are actually 4 `int` fields and one `boolean` field, and in the new message only the the boolean field is required to be changed.

I am in doubt what would be the best way to accomplish this, and thus seeking your help & expert opinion.

I guess building the entire messages once again by creating `builder` objects would be rather too much expensive..

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. It looks like you're reading some data ("Protocol Buffer serialized messages") from a database; such data consists of 5 fields, and you ultimately want to update the value of one field (the boolean one). Can't you use a SQL `UPDATE`?

Comment: @MarcoS Since the messages are serialized, they are presumably all in one SQL column. (Which is bad database design for this problem, probably.)

Comment: @Robin Green: thank you for the explanation: I didn't think about it. So, if messages are serialized than I think you must `SELECT` the ones you want to update, and then process each of them: de-serialize, update boolean field, serialize again, and update record on database ... or change database design, and have a column for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder approach should be cheap enough, especially if you can execute near to the server to minimise latency. However, if the bit field has the first/last field number, it *should* be a single byte update in either the 2nd or last byte, so might be possible in SQL if you like. In fact, as long as you just want to skip the ints (i.e. you don't need to know what they were or change them), even picking out the bool in the middle would be fairly easy.

But try the route using the existing client first; it may be faster than you think.

Comment: I use Cassandra DB which doesnt provide 'update' functionality as such, so anyhow I need to read and then write back a new column to the DB. Thus latency remains the same. But I was asking about if creating a new message & putting in values from parsed PB message is the correct approach for that or if I could edit the message that was parsed back from the read bytes & then send back to DB? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Marcos - once you've transported the data over the network, any local processing time will be barely noticeable and is the least risky approach. So sure, use the builder. If you absolutely needed the most performance, it would also be possible with a reader, but you'd need to be pretty aware of the protocol internals  for that.

Comment: oh, and "a few hundred" - that should be blindingly quick for small messages you describe; i.e. well under a second

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you benchmark and see how long it takes.  You might be able to do this in under a 1 ms, meaning any IO you perform is likely to be more expensive than how you process the data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you redesign your database so that the field in the protocol buffer message that you want to modify, is in a separate database column. Therefore, instead of serializing the entire protocol buffers message in one column (which is what I presume you have now in your database) you would represent it in some other way. Then you can just use a simple SQL `UPDATE` command.

I mean, it makes little sense to use a database designed for *relational* data storage, to store serialized data that needs to be updated. It gets in the way of using SQL efficiently.

Alternatively, I don't know if there are databases specialised for working with protocol buffers, but there certainly are XML databases which are purportedly specialised for processing XML documents, so you could try converting your data to XML and using one of them. It's probably overkill for this one single problem though! But if you are going to have lots of little tasks like this to perform, it might be worthwhile.

However, without more details about what your application and/or database are used for, it's difficult to say what would be best.